# is, at the most, but little

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> The learning and knowledge that we have, **is, at the most, but** little compared with that of which we are ignorant.
>   —Plato

I'm having real trouble understanding how exactly I should parse that sentence grammatically.

Comment: The most we can know is only a little in comparison to how much we don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's deal with the meaning of the phrase. The quote (always attributed to Plato, but I've never found a translation that it appears in) is saying that what we know is small in comparison to what we don't know.

When it come to parsing it, most is quite straightforward - it's a simple comparison of what we have against what we don't have:

> The learning and knowledge that we have, is, at the most,

The 'at the most' suggests that we're dealing with a generalization and that this is considering a best-case example.

> but little compared with that of which we are ignorant.

I suspect that it is the *'but little'* that may be causing a problem as, to many, it may sound a little old-fashioned. The OED gives us:

> With negative emphasis: not much; a (very) small amount or quantity.

It's a usage that Shakespeare was quite keen on:

> Will make but little for his benefit - *Henry VI*
>
> Thou dost me yet but little hurt; thou wilt anon -*The Tempest*
>
> I have but little gold of late, brave Timon -*Timon of Athens*

etc...

Comment: On a related note, I'd be interested if anyone can find where the quotation comes from. Although there are many references attributing it to Plato (without mentioning the work), I've now searched a couple of Plato archives and can't find it in any English translations.